# Pandas where filter resetting data types to default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with column data type set to 'int32' explicitly. When I use filtering using the bracket operators, data type does not change.

```
scripts[scripts['Security Id'] == 'ABB']['Security Code'].head()
```

> 0    500002 Name: Security Code, dtype: int32

However when I use where filtering, data type is reset back to default i.e. float64.

```
(scripts.where(scripts['Security Id'] == 'ABB')
       .dropna())['Security Code'].head()
```

datatype changes back to 'float64'

> 0    500002.0 Name: Security Code, dtype: float64

So I am just wondering why this is the case especially since operator chaining is the idiomatic way of doing things in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of `dtype` in the second case is a consequence of `numpy` having no integer representation of `NaN`. As a result, if you have `NaN` within a numeric column, the `dtype` will cast into `float`.

In your first case:

```
scripts[scripts['Security Id'] == 'ABB']['Security Code'].head()
```

you are just returning a subset of your `scripts` `DataFrame` based on a condition. Since the underlying `DataFrame` is type `int32` the subset will have the same `dtype`.

However, in the second case, `DataFrame.where` returns an object where it passes the values in rows where the condition is `True`, but replaces the value with `np.NaN` otherwise. So you are modifying the `DataFrame` and introducing `NaN` values, which forces `pandas` to cast the column to `float64`.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
scripts = pd.DataFrame({'Security Id': ['ABB', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ABB'],
                        'Security Code': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
scripts['Security Code'] = scripts['Security Code'].astype('int32')

scripts.where(scripts['Security Id'] == 'ABB')

   Security Code Security Id
0            1.0         ABB
1            2.0         ABB
2            NaN         NaN
3            4.0         ABB
Security Code    float64
Security Id       object
dtype: object
```